# How to create a .Gzip file in android and also Encrypt and Decrypt that file?

Tags: android, gzip, encryption

I have an application in that i want to create a .Gzip file and store it into 
a sdacrd?
After that for security purpose i want to encrypt that .Gzip file as well as decrypt.

How can it done?

Comment: I would like to know this answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at GZIP Api here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html

And also this question:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html

And you can encrypt/decrypt using following API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html

And here are examples:
http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings